# angular - ng-show wont remove the ng-hide class when form field becomes invalid

Tags: html, angularjs, validation, ng-show

ng-show has its ng-hide class on form and whenever the field becomes invalid it should remove the class and show error message, but for some reason, it doesnt work

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form id="email-form" name="email-form" ng-controller="loginFormCtrl as ctrl" >
            <div>
                <input ng-model="user.name" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="10" class="w-input username" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" name="name" data-name="Name"  required>
                <span ng-show="email-form['name'].dirty && email-form['name'].$error.maxlength">too long!</span>
                <span ng-show="email-form.name.dirty && email-form.name.$error.minlength">too short!</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input ng-model="user.email" class="w-input" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" name="email" data-name="Email" required>
                <span ng-show="email-form['email'].dirty &&  email-form.email.$error.required">required</span>
                <span ng-show="email-form.email.dirty &&  email-form.email.$error.required">not an email</span>
            </div>
            <div class="w-row">
                <div class="w-col w-col-6 w-col-stack"><a class="button widebutton" ng-click="submit()" href="">Log In</a>
                </div>
                <div class="w-col w-col-6 w-col-stack"><a class="button widebutton"  href="" ng-click="go('/createaccount')">Sign Up</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: `$dirty` not `dirty`

Comment: that was it! combined with the answer below :) thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your form name name="email-form" to name="emailForm". Following the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) you should use something like:

```
<span ng-show="emailForm.email.$dirty && emailForm.email.$error.required">required</span>
<span ng-show="emailForm.email.$dirty && emailForm.email.$error.email">not an email</span>
```

Same with the other two.